# Change value of column from select statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to change the value returned by a select statement.  Currently, when I select a certain column the value returned is either '1', '2', or NULL. I'd like to return a different value in place of '1' and '2' such as "18". I've tried using the `translate` function to no avail. How is this done with postgresql?

Currently was trying:

```
.select("concat_ws(', ', translate(e110618, '12', '18'), e110717, e110519)")
```

When I remove the translate it works but the output (1,2,1) isn't what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `translate()` is really what you need. It does a character-based search/replace, whereas you seem to be looking to match the whole string.

You can use a `case` expression instead. This is standard SQL that works in most RDBMS.

```
case when e110618 in ('1', '2') then 18 else e110618 end
```

If the only other possible value than 1 and 2 is `null`, then this can simplified, since `case` returns `null` by default:

```
case when e110618 in ('1', '2') then 18 end
```

Note: if `e110618` is a numeric datatype (and not a string), then you should remove the single quotes around `1` and `2`.

In your code:

```
select(
    "concat_ws(', ', case when e110618 in ('1', '2') then 18 end, e110717, e110519)"
)
```